# Azure DevOps build pipeline for Angular and Failed to exec build script Node error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, azure-devops

I am working with Azure DevOps CI/CD for Angular 7 project but it is failing with following at the time of building angular code:

> Error: Npm failed with return code: 1

Going through the pipeline task log I found that Node is exiting with following error:

> 2019-05-27T06:57:25.6984762Z npm verb lifecycle fuse@7.1.0~build: CWD: D:\a\1\s\Client
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6984945Z npm info lifecycle fuse@7.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6985117Z npm verb stack Error: fuse@7.1.0 build: `node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev "--prod"`
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6985258Z npm verb stack Exit status 1
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6985401Z npm verb stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6985577Z npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6985721Z npm verb stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6986143Z npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6986311Z npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6986453Z npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6986609Z npm verb pkgid fuse@7.1.0
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6986743Z npm verb cwd D:\a\1\s\Client
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6986877Z npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.14393
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6987017Z npm verb argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "build" "--" "--prod"
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6987169Z npm verb node v10.15.3
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6987304Z npm verb npm  v6.9.0
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6987435Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6987584Z npm ERR! errno 1
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6987890Z npm ERR! fuse@7.1.0 build: `node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev "--prod"`
>   2019-05-27T06:57:25.6988173Z npm ERR! Exit status 1

I tried looking through different threads based upon error keywords but have not found a fix yet. Please note that everything works fine in the development environment.

I am not allowed to attach file or image so I am pasting pipeline YAML here:

```html
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    command: install
    workingDir: Client

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Build Angular'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    customCommand: run build -- --prod
    workingDir: Client

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'angular'
    targetPath: 'Client/dist'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your first task must be install Angular CLI.

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: angular/cli
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: Client
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install @angular/cli -g'
```

Can you try running it to the first step?

Comment: -g returned permission error. So, I tried installing it locally by removing -g:

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: angular/cli
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: Client
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install @angular/cli'

Above worked fine but the error remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get it working after discussion with Microsoft support guys. Here is direct link to [solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/585065/view.html)

Thanks for your support!

Comment: The link no longer works. It's fine to have links as a reference in your solution, but the answer should actually be documented *in* the solution, precisely because links eventually rot.